# Most Effective Way to Decompose / Recompose An Object Hierarchy in .NET 4.5+ / .NET Standard 1.0+ / .NET Core 1.0+

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reflection, .net-core

### Scenario

I have a use case where I need do `decompose` an `hierarchical object tree` into a set of its constituent objects. Later on, I will also need to `recompose` those objects back into their original form (or some variation thereof.)

### Goals

My goals are as follows.

- Determine the `fastest` and most `processor` and/or `memory efficient` ways to `decompose/recompose` the objects. (This code will process millions of objects so saving even a few ticks is useful.)
- Locate any existing `libraries` or `examples` which may facilitate this `decomposition/recomposition` scenario or which may demonstrate how others have done something similar.
- Compile a list of `strategies`, `methods`, and `techniques` for `decomposing` an `object hierarchy` (in `.NET 4.5+`, `.NET Core`) into its elementary objects and `recomposing` those elementary objects back into an hierarchy. **(Note: There is no such thing as too many ideas, too many techniques, or too many examples here.)**

### 'Givens' / Requirements

- This functionality will be implemented in `.NET Core 1.x` and above. Backwards compatibility with `.NET 4.5+` would be a plus.
- The structure of the `object tree` is not necessarily known in advance.

  - The `decomposition component` must be able to work with any provided object tree.
- The `object hierarchy` may be many layers deep.

  - The `decomposition` will run recursively until it reaches the lowest level of the `object tree`. Most objects (except as described below) will be `decomposed`.
  - `Arrays` and `collections` may optionally be kept intact rather than being `decomposed`. This will vary from usage to usage. I would say that generally, `Arrays`, `Dictionaries`, `simple lists` (e.g. `lists of strings`) will generally **not be** `decomposed`. `Complex lists` (e.g. `lists of objects` **will likely** `decompose`.)
- `Recomposition` of object hierarchies may be full or partial.
- During `recomposition`, other objects may be inserted into the object hierarchy (or existing objects may be replaced) to make completely new types of objects.

### Potentially Important Issues Not Yet Considered

I am still at an early stage in analyzing how to accomplish these objectives. (Frankly, I feel like I am flying blind here.) There are probably many important factors I have not considered in any depth. These include:

- Any potential impact of self-referencing `classes`.
- Implications or impact of other potential element or object types.

### Resources I am Currently Reviewing

I have a reasonable idea of *generally* how to accomplish the decomposition and recomposition through reflection. However, I am not confident that I know how to do it well, do it efficiently, or do it in a way that properly handles every issue.

Here is a list of some of the resources I am reviewing now.

- `XmlSerializer` - from .NET reference source https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/System.Xml/System/Xml/Serialization
- `CoreFx` - https://github.com/dotnet/corefx
- `NewtonsoftJson` - https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json
- `ZeroFormatter` - https://github.com/neuecc/ZeroFormatter
- `MessagePack-Csharp` - for .NET Core - extremely efficient. https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp
- `Protobuf.net` https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net

### Demo Class / Object Hierarchy

I have created a very simple **for-demonstration-purposes-only** `class hierarchy` which represents the types of elements I would expect to find in the object hierarchies which we will process.

These include:

- `ValueType` - (e.g. integer) **Property**
- `String` - **Property**
- `DateTime` - **Property**
- `Custom Class` - **Property**
- `Dictionary` - **Collection**
- `Lists` - **Collection**
- `Array` - **Field**

There is a single base class which generates an `Id` of type `Guid` on the parent and all children.

```
public class EntityBase
{
    public EntityBase()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

The `root object` in the demo hierarchy is of type `Person`. It contains various general properties of type `string`, `int`, and `DateTime` just as one would find in most any class. It also contains `List` and `Dictionary` `collection classes`, an `array`, and a reference to single custom object.

```
public class Person : EntityBase
{
    public Person()
    {
        Phones = new List<Phone>();
        Addresses = new List<Address>();
        Passwords = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        FavoriteFood = new FoodPreference();
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public FoodPreference FavoriteFood {get; set;}
    public string[] Dogs = { "Shayna", "Sport" };
    public Dictionary<string, string> Passwords { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

There is a `collection` of phone numbers.

```
public class Phone : EntityBase
{
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

There is a `collection` of postal addresses.

```
public class Address : EntityBase
{
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

There is a `custom class` with some detail on a favorite food.

```
public class FoodPreference : EntityBase
{
    public string FoodCategory { get; set; }
    public string FoodName { get; set; }
}
```

Just to put it all together, here is a sample method which populates the heirarchy with `dummy data`.

```
    public static Person BuildPerson()
    {
        return new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Anthony",
            LastName = "Gatlin",
            Weight = 154, // I wish. :)
            DateOfBirth = DateTime.Parse("01/01/1970"),
            Phones = new List<Phone>
            {
                new Phone {PhoneNumber = "601-555-1212"},
                new Phone {PhoneNumber = "601-555-1213"}
            },
            Addresses = new List<Address>
            {
                new Address {StreetAddress = "111 Country Rd", City = "Heidelberg", State = "MS", PostalCode = "39349"}
            },
            Passwords = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"google","googlepass" },
                {"skype","skypepass" },
                {"facebook","facebookpass" }
            },
            FavoriteFood = new FoodPreference { FoodCategory = "Baked Goods", FoodName = "Chocolate Cake" }
        };
    }
```

> The sample object hierarchy can be retrieved from https://dotnetfiddle.net/AyjXiK.

### Output From Sample Data

Following is a simple `JSON dump` of `sample data` generated for this hierarchy.

```
{
  "Dogs": [
    "Shayna",
    "Sport"
  ],
  "FirstName": "Anthony",
  "LastName": "Gatlin",
  "Weight": 154,
  "DateOfBirth": "1970-01-01T00:00:00",
  "FavoriteFood": {
    "FoodCategory": "Baked Goods",
    "FoodName": "Chocolate Cake",
    "Id": "0c516c4d-ff64-4b8d-bb44-b430aa8d3ce5"
  },
  "Passwords": {
    "google": "googlepass",
    "skype": "skypepass",
    "facebook": "facebookpass"
  },
  "Phones": [
    {
      "PhoneNumber": "601-555-1212",
      "Id": "57bdfdcb-4232-40e4-aab8-4c6387029257"
    },
    {
      "PhoneNumber": "601-555-1213",
      "Id": "b591afc3-6e91-4030-ad26-00beefceca43"
    }
  ],
  "Addresses": [
    {
      "StreetAddress": "111 Country Rd",
      "City": "Heidelberg",
      "State": "MS",
      "PostalCode": "39349",
      "Id": "94cc5e37-db96-44b7-869a-818968d99ddd"
    }
  ],
  "Id": "629ae27e-17aa-49ad-823a-2cd2ebf0cb66"
}
```

### Expected Result

Once the objects have been `decomposed` from the `object hierarchy`, I will end up storing some sort of `simple hierarchy` which will allow me to `recompose` the objects.

Given the following `Id` `Guids` ...

- `629ae27e-17aa-49ad-823a-2cd2ebf0cb66` // Person Id
- `0c516c4d-ff64-4b8d-bb44-b430aa8d3ce5` // FavoriteFood
- `57bdfdcb-4232-40e4-aab8-4c6387029257` // Phone1 Id
- `b591afc3-6e91-4030-ad26-00beefceca43` // Phone2 Id
- `94cc5e37-db96-44b7-869a-818968d99ddd` // Address Id

we may end up with a very simple hierarchy like so.

```
{  
   "Person":{  
      "Id":"629ae27e-17aa-49ad-823a-2cd2ebf0cb66",
      "FavoriteFood":{  
         "Id":"0c516c4d-ff64-4b8d-bb44-b430aa8d3ce5"
      },
      "Phone":[  
         {  
            "Id":"57bdfdcb-4232-40e4-aab8-4c6387029257"
         },
         {  
            "Id":"b591afc3-6e91-4030-ad26-00beefceca43"
         }
      ],
      "Address":[  
         {  
            "Id":"94cc5e37-db96-44b7-869a-818968d99ddd"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Each object with `dependencies` will have its own `one-level` `dependency tree` similar to the one above.

*The above hierarchy model is merely conceptual and does not reflect how the data will actually be stored. I am completely open to (read enthusiastically seeking) ideas on better ways to do this.*

Just as a side note, each of the elementary objects will actually be serialized to `JSON` or `MsgPack` and stored with its key (Id) for quick retrieval. We will be able to `fully` or `partially reassemble` the objects from the hierarchy when required.

### Thank You!

I am really looking for any guidance, recommendations, advice, ideas, tips, examples, code snippets, libraries, or anything else you can offer that will help me to accomplish this task efficiently.

**Thank you so very much, in advance, for your help! It is extremely appreciated.**

Comment: Could you give any info as to why you need to do this?

Comment: Matt, I would prefer to limit the detail for now so as not to distract from the topic under discussion. The project involves a "new" way to store & process data--somewhat of a hybrid between a relational & a document database. By decoupling individual objects, we can perform much more rapid & flexible analysis & queries on individual items (the elementary objects) than could be done by hitting whole (& sometimes very large docs) from a data store.  Breaking an object hierarchy into its elements allows it to be treated much like data in a relational database without the unwanted constraints.

Comment: Thought it sounded like that, one architectural style for exactly that is to use a doc db as your initial/primary store which your app talks to then decompose in the background to a relational store. Often then the decomposing step doesn't need to be super quick in this setup as the relational data is used for reporting or sent to downstream systems. Sounds like perf is critical to you but maybe this style would make it less so.

Comment: If I needed to do this sort of thing, I would go with NewtonSoft because there are plenty of examples, questions on SO, documentation and it is pretty customizable. Plus I find it easy to use.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, Thanks for the feedback. I use Newtonsoft.JSON. It is very useful for serializing and deserializing objects. However, I am not sure that it the best choice for decomposing/composing objects. Also, JSON is only of multiple outputs for my data. In reality, more of my data will end up in MsgPack format--which NewtonSoft.JSON does not provide.

Comment: @Matt, in this approach, there will be no relational store. At the moment, Redis (which is super fast) sits at the core of everything. Redis is amazing but many people don't like to use it because it is such a departure from relational data stores. Many people like MongoDb and similar products, but there are performance and other limitations that make them impractical for many situations. A hybridized solution that could wrap Redis or similar database could likely offer most of the benefits of a document database while offering many of the benefits of a relational store.

Comment: Your `question` is very `hard` **for** `me` to `read` because of `all the` code-formatting `of` non-code `text` and **all** the bold **stuff**.

Comment: @UweKeim, I am sorry the visual cues are distracting for you. They actually help me to better see the important elements in the post. I can certainly understand that not everyone may have the same preferences.

Comment: I'm curious to know what you decided to use in the end? I have a need to send data from a .Net framework 4.5 app over to .Net Core on AWS, via SQS and I'm looking for the most effective method, I'm thinking you might have some good advice. Thanks